# this.getView() returns undefined after event callback

Tags: javascript, sapui5

Inside my ui5 controller I call my method in the `onBeforeRending` function. Inside that method I call `this.getView().getId()` which I require for a library I am using, and that is fine:

```
onBeforeRendering: function () {
    this.func();
}, 

func: function() {
    this.getView().getId();
}
```

Later, I have an onClick event handler for an html control:

```
click: function () {
    const controller = sap.ui.controller("Project.controller.Controller");
    controller.func();
}
```

When `this.getView()` is called from `controller.func` I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getId' of undefined
  func
  click
```

I realize this means that getView() returns `undefined`, but I am not sure why. Checking the `this` reference inside of `func` in the second call reveals it has access to the other functions in the controller but not `getView`.

Edit:

I solved the problem by binding the view to a variable then capturing it in the on click callback.

```
let view = this.getView()
```

then later

```
click: function() {
    const controller = sap.ui.controller("Project.controller.Controller");

    controller.getView = function () {
        return view;
    };

    controller.func();
}
```

Comment: Where is the onClick handler? Is this in a custom control? I think you're just fetching a controller, it's not connected to the current view if that's the intention.

Comment: @Jorg How do I connect it to the view I want?

Comment: So it is a custom control? The answer will depend on what it is

Comment: @Jorg Yes, it is a highchart.js graph but it is just imported and placed into the view and operates like a normal highchart graph. No custom control is created and registered.

Comment: @Jorg I have figured out you can do `sap.ui.xmlview("Project.view.View")` to get a view but this seems to create a new one and doesn't have the same id as the current view. How do I get the current view with the proper id?

Comment: where is `click: function() {...` ? in a fragment? or a view? you should have a handle to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

Attempting to answer because there's to much to stick in a comment.

If you're using a third party library it's still often useful to wrap the code in a custom control. The control can be reused in various other applications afterwards and will allow the binding of both data and handlers from outside of the control as provided by the controller of the view you're placing the control in.

In addition, if you're using SAPUI5 instead of OpenUI5 you'll have access to [VizFrame](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.viz.ui5.controls.VizFrame) which is the UI5 wrapper for D3 (which would replace this solution all together).

Here's the skeleton code for a custom control. Replace the paths and namespaces etc:

```
sap.ui.define(
  ['sap/ui/core/Control', '../path/to/highcharts'],
  function(Control) {
    "use strict";

    return Control.extend("my.namespace.graph", {
      metadata: {
          events : {
            "graphClick" : {}
          }
      },

      init: function() {
        //initialisation. 
      },

      renderer: function(element, control) {
        element.write(`<div id="my-graph"></div>`);
      },

      onAfterRendering: function() {
        //do whatever you need to bind a handler to your graph. You can call a function on 
        //this control like this.onClick, below. 
      },

      onClick: function(data) {
        this.fireGraphClick(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

You can import this control into your view and use it like you use any other control. `graphClick` is then what you use:

```
<controls:graph graphClick="myControllerFunction" />
```

Don't forget to add controls to the xml namespace...

You can find more information about custom controls in the [UI5 documentation](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/topic/d12d2ee6a5454d799358d425f9e7c4db)

Comment: events should be outside properties. that's children of metadata. renderer function is wrong, need to add control data.

Comment: I've moved the events. I don't really know what is in the control data to be honest, but adding ui5 control classes and ID's might affect the third party library.